# Understanding System Calls and how .net accesses the Kernel

Tags: architecture, operating-system

Lately, I have been reading about operating systems design.  The idea that all user space programs utilize Kernel services via a "System Call Interface" have got me thinking further into this raising some questions below.

1. Is system call implemented in specific language like "C/C++" on each operating system or it is some sort of assembly language or machine code?
2. Operating System provides an API on top of the System calls.  The APIs are usually written in C or C++.  If System call is an Assembly language how those API generates Assembly code?
3. Does Java Byte Code or MSIL code converts into API Calls or they are directly converted to System calls?
4. How does system call gets the attention of Kernel?  Does it send some sort of interrupt?

Answer (score 2):

> How does system call gets the attention of Kernel? Does it send some sort of interrupt?

The operating system defines a table of kernel mode handlers for interrupts, faults, and traps. On system systems there are multiple tables (e.g., interrupts separate) but logically you can consider it one table.

When an interrupt, fault, or trap occurs the CPU looks up the entry for in the table for the corresponding event. That entry specifies a routine for handling that event.

For system services, the processor will define one or more instructions that explicitly trigger a trap that invokes a system service. Something like this:

```
 CHKM #12  ; Trigger a trap causing entry in to kernel mode to be handled by routine #12.
```

> Is system call implemented in specific language like "C/C++" on each operating system or it is some sort of assembly language or machine code?

Usually it is assembly language but sometimes it can be written in C.

> Operating System provides an API on top of the System calls. The APIs are usually written in C or C++. If System call is an Assembly language how those API generates Assembly code?

Calling the system requires assembly language to execute the trap instruction and to set up the hardware registers for the system service. Invariably, operating systems provide wrapper functions that can be called from high level languages that will unpack the parameters, cause the trap, and repack the parameters returned from the system service.

> Does Java Byte Code or MSIL code converts into API Calls or they are directly converted to System calls?

Byte code would not know anything about system services. They would have to be called by the virtual machine.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.    On the Byte Code, what I meant to ask was does the "JVM" or ".Net CLR" translates the "IL code" directly to "machine language or system call" or does it call the API wrapper function provided by the target platform operating system.                                           For Example: Lets say IL/Byte code is int i = 4 + 2*6;                                Will the .Net or Java run time generates the "machine code" which is executed by processor?

Comment: Similarly, if the instruction is File f = File.open("someFile.txt");     Will the java/.net run time interpret or translates that to a "system call" or would it use "Wrapper API" sitting above the system call interface.

Comment: I would think that the "run times" doesn't use the "Operating system" api but rather generates the "System Call" or "Machine Code" directly when interpreting the intermediate language code.

Answer (score 1):

1. Most of the system calls are implemented using c/c++, assembly language is used in case of direct access(DMA) to the device.
2. In Most of the scenario system calls or other system services will be loaded during the run time as dynamic linking libraries. So it does not even matter in which language the sys calls are implemented as the code already compiled and got converted/being converted to the native machine code.
3. There is no need for byte code/IL to be converted to sys calls. run time/virtual machine will simply utilize the system services(including system calls) during run time.
4. System call by itself a type of interrupt(hardware interrupt being another one) and the routine for system call exists in the kernel itself. So when a runtime or virtual machine need to invoke system call, the operating system do a switch(from user to kernel mode), executes the sys call and switch back to the kernel to user mode.